# iOS - Open a different Stroryboard based on the device size

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have created an app in Swift and I want it to be available in both iPhone and iPad, but I would like the iPad to have a couple different layout variables, such as bigger buttons and pictures. Using auto-layout or Size Classes with constraints wasn't working and not letting me put them where I want them, so I was wondering how to make it so that when I open the simulator with an iPad, it opens the storyboard with the different View Controller layouts. I made a duplicate storyboard so I have main.storyboard and the copy is mainiPad.storyboard for the iPad only. If this can be done, please let me know! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

- This [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/)  is the old way, when You simply add iPad suffix in the file name.
- This [Post](https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/) is the new way, introduced in Xcode 6; You simply select the storyboard name for ipad and iphone family in application plist file.